# How soon after giving birth can a cat be spayed?

Tags: cats, desexing

The cat is pregnant and we want to get her spayed, we don't want her to accidentally get pregnant again nor do we want to put her or the kittens at risk.  How long do we need to wait?  If she is still nursing the kittens does that impact spaying?

FYI - I see there is question about a [9 month old kitten/cat that is still nursing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6228)

Comment: I did some research on this and am finding all ranges of answer [5-6 weeks](http://www.spayusa.org/pet-owners-faq.php) and [2 weeks after weening](http://www.cat-pregnancy-report.com/can-a-cat-get-spayed-right-after-delivery.html) there are some suggesting sooner (as a cat can get pregnant before the kittens are weened and some longer. All seemed to be opinion based without good references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When Should She Be Spayed?**

I wasn't able to find any definitive information about when a nursing mother should be spayed, but spaying nursing mothers seems common in TNR (trap neuter return) groups (it's better to spay a cat that you have in a trap now, then try to trap her again later).

Ally Cat Allies (a leading TNR group) [states](http://www.alleycat.org/page.aspx?pid=977) (based, presumably, on their 25 years of experience in TNR advocacy):

> Nursing mother cats continue to produce milk after being spayed, and can continue to nurse their kittens.

**Best Spaying Technique for Nursing Mother**

If you want to get her spayed while she is nursing, you can call the local veterinarians and ask if they are experienced in flank spaying.

In the US, cats are normally spayed with an incision along their midline (the belly), but in UK ([at least in 2006](http://veterinaryrecord.bmj.com/content/159/10/309.abstract)) the incision is more commonly located along the flank (along the side).

The benefit of a flank spay for a nursing mother is that the incision is less likely to be affected by any leaking milk, and you will be able to monitor the incision without bothering the kittens.

Answer (score 3):

At my previous clinic we would spay 2 weeks after weaning. Gives the mother enough time to feed her babies and recover as producing milk, caring for kittens can be hard on their system.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to spay the cat after weaning as some of them are getting pregnant while feeding.  As to **TNRM** helping with spaying, here in Kuala Lumpur, they were contacted for paid help in spaying about 6 females and once they were told that we will be monitoring them on their return, we had no more response from the Manager, Stuart, now we have kittens from 5 of the 6 females we asked to be spayed. Would like to take the poor little things to **TNRM** doors, if there is one, that is.

Answer (score -1):

A vet here in the Philippines recommended 6 months after having kittens. That would be 6 more heats to go through, and does not agree with all the other experts.

Answer (score -2):

Since they go trough puberty at around 6 months, so you should probably get her spayed at around 6-7 months old.

I recommend you get her spayed at 6 1/3 months, so that gives time to cool down from puberty and it won't be too late.

One more thing; Cats go through heat about every 2 weeks.

What I'm trying to say is: The SOONEST you can get them spayed is the day after they have puberty.

Comment: Cats reach sexual maturity at 4 months, their heat cycle is ~3-4 weeks, and the question is about the mother cat, not the kittens.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't exactly answer the question, also it would be nice if you either include sources for the numbers or correct them if there are opinions that they are incorrect, thanks.

Answer (score -6):

A female cat should be spayed before she has a litter. There are far too many unwanted cats in the world already.

As to spaying her now, consult a vet.

Comment: Are you suggesting the cat should be spayed while pregnant?

Comment: No, I'm stating that female cats should be spayed before they have the opportunity to become pregnant. As to spaying a cat while they are pregnant, it is not done very often but it can be done and is considered an abortion combined with what is effectively a hysterectomy.

Comment: How dos this address the question? It appear the cat in questions is already pregnant.

Comment: I am aware that the cat is pregnant. I was simply tried to give a nudge in the right direction so that the person will at least consider neutering and spaying in the future before it's too late, as in this case. I did, however, tell her to consult her vet as to when the cat can be spayed. I was a bit amazed that James read what I wrote as though I was suggesting a spay and abortion. I am surprised that you think I was not aware that the cat was pregnant, I did read and understand the question.